# Python Concat String

Tags: python

I want to concat .old to a filename before I rename it with a function

Will this work:

```
old =   RemoteFileName + '.out'
ftp.rename (RemoteFileName,old)
```

Comment: So what is the problem here?

Comment: In your question you write that you want to concatenate `.old` but in your example code you concatenate `.out`. Which is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that code should work.

If the value of `RemoteFileName` is `readme.txt` then your first line creates a new string with the value `readme.txt.out` and assigns it to the variable `old`. The value of `RemoteFileName` is not changed.